# Помогите войти в MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint

Проблема достаточно частая, перепробовал все советы со англоязычного stack`a, но не получается. когда-то устанавливал MySQL клиент и сервер, баловался, сейчас понадобилось всё нормально установить, через [эту шпаргалку](http://zettahelp.ru/blogs/Ubuntu/kak-polnostyu-udalit-mysql-na-ubuntu-i-postavit-vse-zanovo.php) подчистил всё, что связано было MySQL Server&Client и сейчас устанавливал по новому, через

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

по идее во время установки должны предложить установить пароль для root, но такого не произошло.

Когда всё установилось, ввожу команду `mysql -u root`

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Пробовал выполнять вот такие вот действия:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

После чего получил вот это:

> 2019-02-26T15:23:51.419680Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
>   2019-02-26T15:23:51.425030Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
>   2019-02-26T15:23:51.429211Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.

Comment: Ну а просто ввести `sudo mysql` не пробовали? И вообще, о какой версии MySQL идет речь? От этого будут зависеть рецепты "лечения". Если версия 5.7 или свежее, то установить пароль, вроде бы, можно через команду `sudo mysql_secure_installation`.

Comment: ввёл sudo mysql_secure_installation и получил sudo mysql_secure_installation, далее нужно было ввести пароль который я либо не помню, либо даже не создавал. по крайней мере при переустановке я точно не создавал. Версия mysql 5.7.25

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то после `mysql_secure_installation` пароль предложат ввести только если отказаться от первых двух пунктов (что-то про дополнительные проверки и про аутентификацию через сокет). Если не отказались от новой аутентификации (через сокет), то и пароля не будет. И тогда, вроде, вход будет разрешен только через `sudo mysql`.

Comment: @Vladimir `sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
` то есть не важно что я там нажму, он в любом случае просит пароль

Comment: Так а что с командой `sudo mysql`? Так тоже не пускает?

Comment: @Vladimir верно. Может быть я не всё удалил и какие-то Настройки остались? В таком случае я не знаю как удалить остальное, я вроде всевозможные способы проверки и удаления делал

Comment: @СотниЛичностей вы же явно не выполнили настройку mysql_secure_installation , попробуйте и потом произведите вход с помощью mysql -u root

Comment: @Slava можно поподробнее объяснить? у меня любые действия связанные с mysql требуют пароля, который я понятию не имею какой и есть ли он вообще, ну судя по тому, что говорит система, он всё-таки есть

Comment: Ну а заходить с паролем "root" пробовали вообще?

Comment: Попробуйте вручную создать эту директорию, дать на неё права пользователю mysql и перезапустить сервер
1) mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
2) chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld